# Using curl, how can i call a php class and a function inside the class from a form i have on another website (different server)

Tags: php, html, post, soap, curl

site1 has the php function and site 2 has a form, both sites are on different servers. What's the most concise way to accomplish this task?

The form on site 2 is a very simple login with "email" and "password".

The php class on site 1 is called Shopper and i need to run the login method inside of the shopper class if the credentials are correct on the form on site 2.

I feel way out of my element here.. would something like this work and if so how would i instantiate the Shopper class and run the login function? Do i need to use SOAP protocol?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
public function login($password) {

global $db;

if (!$this->get_email()) {
    return false;
}

// Log them in now that we know who they are. 
$vars = array();
$vars[] = array(':i_email_id', $this->get_email());
$vars[] = array(':i_password', $password);

// This also exists, but is not yet in use:
// $token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.login_by_username(:i_username, :i_password)', $vars);
$token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.Login_by_Email(:i_email_id, :i_password)', $vars);
// todo: what if it's bad credentials?

if ($token == null) {
    return false;

} else {
    $this->set_sign_in_token($token);
    return $this->get_sign_in_token();
}
```

}

---

Just for clarification:

Login page (siteB):

```
<form id='register' action='http://siteA/test/profile' onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Log In</legend><br/>
<label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
<label for="password">Password*:</label>  
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</fieldset>
</form>


<?php

$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$shopper = new Shopper($username);
$token = $shopper->login($username, $password);

echo json_encode(array("token" => $token));

print_r ($_POST);

?>
```

Action page (siteA):

```
$shopper = new Shopper($email);
$shopper->login($password);

$cInit = curl_init("http://siteB/test/login");
curl_setopt_array($cInit, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>urlencode(implode("&", array("email" => $email, "password" => $password)))
    ));

    $content = curl_exec($cInit);
    $err     = curl_errno($cInit);
    $errmsg  = curl_error($cInit);

    $results = json_decode($content);

    //$results =  array("token" => "pleasework" );
```

Does that look right?

Comment: form action can be a url, i see no need for CURL

Comment: no more than you need credentials to access google.com

Comment: <form action="http://site1/profile" method="POST"></form> Well, i thought about something like this, but how would it access the file? I'd imagine i need credentials to access a different server. So would what i wrote above be appropriate and how would i integrate my login function?

Comment: Did i just lose the plot?

Comment: I'll post the login function above in my code and i'll need to return a token from the server after the login initially.

Comment: I'm still quite perplexed,  @Dagon please help.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to check if the user is registered as well? So maybe I'm calling two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the login form on Site B to perform some task as well as get a token from site A, then you can use cURL for that. You would go to the form action page (use Firebug to find out where the form is posting to) and add the cURL stuff there. For example

Site A:

```
<?php 
    //blah blah blah whatever the login method does for Site B

    //Now get a token from site A
    $cInit = curl_init("http://siteA.com/api/somepage.php");
    curl_setopt_array($cInit, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> urlencode(implode("&", array("username" => $username, "someOtherVar" => $var)))
    ));

    $content = curl_exec($cInit); 
    $err     = curl_errno($cInit); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error($cInit) ;

    $results = json_decode($content);
    // results should equal array("token" => "whateverYourTokenIs")

?>
```

Site B

```
<?php
//This is the code for http://siteA.com/api/somepage.php
$user = $_POST["username"];
$var = $_POST["someOtherVar"];

$thing = new SomeClass();
$token = $thing->GetToken($user, $var);

echo json_ecode(array("token" => $token));

 ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated all my code above can you just glance at it to make sure it looks correct. Thanks in advance Mike.

Comment: I might of put that backwards, curl goes on the page with the form?

Comment: The cURL code belongs on whatever page the login form on site A posts to. The Site B page is the page that is receiving the cURL request from your other site.

Comment: I can't figure this out for the life of me Mike. I'll repost what i got up top when it comes to the login page and the profile.php page which should be running the curl.

Answer (score 0):

About the @Mike answer (Instead of commenting this answer, I write another because php code looks better):

The

```
urlencode(implode("&", array("username" => $username, "someOtherVar" => $var)))
```

code don't works for me: it only concatenate the array values, not the keys. I have found this simpliest php core function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php and this is the resulting code:

```
$params = array("username" => $username, "someOtherVar" => $var)
[...]
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> http_build_query($params)
[...]
```